# Copy and inserting HTML elements into new pop-up block

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml, appendchild, createelement

I want to completely copy all elements

```
<div id="articleFull"> ... </div>
```

(+ div inclusive) with their content in a new pop-up window

```
<div id="newPopUp"> ... </div>
```

```html
<div id="articleFull">
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <img src="1.png" />
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <h3>Test title</h3>
    <img src="1.png" />
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

I tried to do this simple method:
http://jsfiddle.net/ApBSN/3/

```html
articleFull = document.getElementById('articleFull');

function copyHtml(){
    div = document.createElement('div')
    div.id = 'newPopUp';
    document.body.appendChild(div);

    var t = document.getElementById('articleFull');
    div.appendChild(t);
}
```

It works... BUT the function does not copy the code, and moves it from one place to another, effectively removing it from its original location. I just want to duplicate the block. Yes, I understand that the page can not be 2 "ID", but with this, I'll take care of myself more.

Ideas?

Answer (score 3):

you can try Clone if interested in Jquery...http://api.jquery.com/clone/ this will duplicate the html rather then replacing it as in case of append

i have updated your http://jsfiddle.net/ApBSN/9/ but now you need to work on css

```
var t1 = document.getElementById('newPopUp');

var t = document.getElementById('articleFull');

$(t).clone().appendTo(t1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I am still very badly know javascript to use frameworks. I need example in pure js for a better understanding of the principles of language

Comment: Yes, you understood perfectly what I want - thanks for implementation. But it uses jQuery, so I'll try Googling on themes jquery-clone with pure js. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly this should do it:

```
function copyHtml(){
    div = document.createElement('div')
    div.id = 'newPopUp';
    document.body.appendChild(div);

    var t = document.getElementById('articleFull');
    t.id = "articleFull2";
    div.appendChild(t);
}
```

Comment: I just want to duplicate the entire div = "articleFull" in "newPopUp". If you look here http://jsfiddle.net/ApBSN/3/, we see that when we press the button - the first "articleFull" is removed and only the parent <div id="otherDiv">. But I need him to stay on in "otherDiv", but a copy of it also appeared in the new popup - "newPopUp"